# Device not Receiving Notifications from Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ionic-framework, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am facing this SO issue opened on [github](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin/issues/15). I am getting the exact same stack trace. The last post says solution is to either add `FacebookSDK` or to remove `ObjC` flag from Linker settings.

### Issue 1

I downloaded the `FacebookSDK.framework` from this [Tutorial link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial) and the build errors are vanished but I am still not able to get notifications.
No errors and no stack trace in logs.

### Issue 2

The solution says to add `FacebookSDK.framework` to Xcode project. However, the [latest SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) no longer contains the framework file. After I installed the pkg I have  the files below
[image]

I added all files to the project but still no good.

Can any one please guide me to make Parse Work with iOS?

Note: Using Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8

Comment: what do you mean _parse_ isn't receiving notifications. I think you should clarify as thats probably not possible. What is it exactly that your trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry for misleading title. I am facing the issue opened in github.(first link) and after implementing the solution from that discussion, build errors are gone but device is not receiving notifications. (Issue 1)  and the post says use facebookSDK framework, which is not available in latest package.(issue 2)

Comment: Have you imported the Facebook frameworks that comes with the Parse SDK when you download it?